# Geometry.Combine doesn't work for curves

Tags: wpf

I want to combine 2 curves like this:
[image]
Then here is my code:

```
// Create a path to draw a geometry with.
Path myPath = new Path();
myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
myPath.StrokeThickness = 1;
var gmy1 = (StreamGeometry)StreamGeometry.Parse("M100,100C110,118.333333333333 138.333333333333,206.666666666667 160,210 181.666666666667,213.333333333333 205,123.333333333333 230,120 255,116.666666666667 280,186.666666666667 310,190 340,193.333333333333 396.666666666667,156.666666666667 410,140 423.333333333333,123.333333333333 393.333333333333,98.3333333333333 390,90");
var gmy2 = (StreamGeometry)StreamGeometry.Parse("M180,241.25L180,241.25 230,290 300,246.66667175293 330,160");
var gmy = Geometry.Combine(gmy1, gmy2, GeometryCombineMode.Union, null);
myPath.Data = gmy;
// Add path shape to the UI.
this.panel1.Children.Add(myPath);
```

But the result is this:

[image]

How to combine the curves in WPF?
And because of the project limitation, we have to implement this without layout and xaml. That means we need the result type is Geometry.

Comment: Any reason not to combine them as strings before parsing? If you concatenate those two strings and parse the resulting string, that gets what you want.

Comment: Thanks！ this could solve my problem. I never thought about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More general than concatenating path strings:

If you have a set of arbitrary Geometries and want to group them, use a `GeometryGroup`:

```
Geometry gmy1 = ...;
Geometry gmy2 = ...;
var gmy = new GeometryGroup();
gmy.Children.Add(gmy1);
gmy.Children.Add(gmy2);
myPath.Data = gmy;
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
Path myPath = new Path();
myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
myPath.StrokeThickness = 1;
var gmy1 = (StreamGeometry)StreamGeometry.Parse("M100,100C110,118.333333333333 138.333333333333,206.666666666667 160,210 181.666666666667,213.333333333333 205,123.333333333333 230,120 255,116.666666666667 280,186.666666666667 310,190 340,193.333333333333 396.666666666667,156.666666666667 410,140 423.333333333333,123.333333333333 393.333333333333,98.3333333333333 390,90");
var gmy2 = (StreamGeometry)StreamGeometry.Parse("M180,241.25L180,241.25 230,290 300,246.66667175293 330,160");

var gmy = (StreamGeometry)StreamGeometry.Parse(gmy1.ToString() + gmy2.ToString());

myPath.Data = gmy;
// Add path shape to the UI.
this.panel1.Children.Add(myPath);
```

The path definition language is a language. Use it as one. `StreamGeometry.ToString()` unparses a `Geometry` back to its Path Definition Language representation, which you can then merge with another one.

Note that this works because each starts with a `M` for Move command: It starts a new line. I don't *think* there's any realistic case where you'd run into any trouble with that (and it won't let you start with `L` for Line), but theory's not exactly my strongest subject.

Answer (score 0):

Just add both of them to a `Grid` or `Canvas`, `Combine` does a intersecting combination, you just seem to want to overlay them. Alternatively add both of them to a `GeometryGroup` and add that to your panel.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But because of the project limitation, we have to implement this without layout and xaml. Is there any similar method to Combine for Curves?

Comment: What are you talking about? You already call `this.panel1.Children.Add`, you just need to call that twice.

Comment: You can also use a geometry group.

Comment: That code is just a sample to explain my problem. It is not our product code. I understand your point. Thanks anyway.